# Use of uninitialized value inside a print

Tags: html, perl

I have Perl code behind a web server, and I combined that Perl script with pure HTML. The important part looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<ENDHTML;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
        <head>
    ...
        </head>
        <body class="landing">
        ...
                <section class="feature 6u$ 12u$(small)">
                <h3 class="title">some title</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
        </section>
        ...
    </body>
    </html>
ENDHTML
```

When somebody opens the web page, this error message will appear in logs:

```
2022/06/27 13:28:44 [error] 7811#100158: *106 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Use of uninitialized value $12 in concatenation (.) or string at /path/to/file/index.pl line 78.
```

I know this is because of `use warnings;`, and if I disable it, then nothing will appear in the log. But, it would be nice if I could ignore the part of script from `print <<ENDHTML;` to `ENDHTML` because they are part of the HTML code. Is there a way to make this happen and I can also `use warnings;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your here-doc is interpolating variables within the string because you used a bare `ENDHTML` without explicit quotes.  This is the same as using double quotes: `"`.

If you use single quotes, you will avoid variable interpolation, and this will eliminate the warning message.  Change:

```
print <<ENDHTML;
```

to:

```
print <<'ENDHTML';
```

You can retain `use warnings;`.  Keep in mind that if your here-doc does have variables which you haven't shown, they will not be interpolated either.

Refer to [quote-like operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) (search for `EOF`)

Answer (score 5):

It's the dollar signs in your heredoc string. Perl thinks these are variables.

```
<!--                                      XXXX        -->
                <section class="feature 6u$ 12u$(small)">
```

You need to escape them, like this:

```
                <section class="feature 6u\$ 12u\$(small)">
```

Although I wonder what kind of HTML that is. You can't have dollar signs and parentheses [as part of class names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1331451).

More details on `$12`:

Perl ignores the space after the `$`, because a dollar sign can't stand on its own in Perl syntax, and treats the numbers `12` after it as a variable name. `$12` would refer to the 12th capture group of a regular expression match. Variable names that start with numbers cannot have letters afterwards, so it's `$12` and not `$12u`.